# Erlang: How to pipe stdin input from a file to an erlang program and match eof?

Tags: erlang, pipe, stdin, eof

How to pipe input from a file as stdin to an erlang program running in the shell as well as standalone?

I have a file `hr.erl` and I compile it from the shell. There is a function in it which accepts input from stdin using `io:fread()`. I have written a case expression with guards where if it matches `{ok, [0]}` it should terminate. Instead of `0`, I actually need it to be `eof`.

1. How to send eof when running in a shell?
2. I have a file `inp.txt` with values `1` `2` `3` and `0` on each line. How can I pass it using the `<` pipe operator? Is there anything like `erl -hr <inp.txt`? Can I pipe it to stdin within the shell.

Here is my program so far (updated to include `eof`).

```
-module(hr).
-export([main/0]).    

r(L) ->
    case io:fread("", "~d") of
        eof -> 
            io:format("eof~n", []),
            ok;
        {ok, [0]} ->
            io:format("terminate~n", []),
            lists:reverse(L);
        {ok, [N]} ->
            io:format("inp ~p~n", [N]),
            r([N|L])
    end.

main() -> r([]).
```

From shell

```
1> c(hr).
{ok,hr}
2> hr:main().
1
inp 1
2
inp 2
3
inp 3
0
terminate
[1,2,3]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to pipe input when using [escript](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html). Write the erlang program without module or export info, with `main(_)` function, i.e., in `escript` compatible way. Then we can pipe input using `cat` like

```
cat inp.txt | escript hr.erl
```

This works and program terminates when it encounters `eof`. But I still don't know why it's not working when using redirect operator `<`.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the Erlang FAQs:

http://www.erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#id49435

Comment: I compiled and am running it like `erl -noshell -s hr main < inp.txt`,  which displays `inp 1` `inp 2` `inp 3` on the console and stays there. Can you show me what the command is in this case? The program is not matching `eof`.

Comment: Also, it's not printing the last line which in this case is `0`.

Comment: The `rot13` program crashed when I run it under cygwin `cat inp.txt | erl -noshell -s rot13 rot13 | wc`. The error obtained is 
`Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
      1       4     163`

Comment: Have you tried on a real platform (i.e., a UNIX?). Windows is seriously flaky for most of these things. The support is there, but the underlying system is so different from traditional UNIX that I am willing to bet that may be the problem. Erlang is rarely used to process command lines like those, so there is less support for that kind of operation.

Comment: Okay, I will try it on Debian. One of the roadblocks I face with functional languges is when dealing with these kind of input outputs. It's not that straight forward like that of say Groovy or python. Anyway, will look for a way to make this work.

Comment: Erlangs strength is to run large application-server appliances rather than small command-line tools. Look for, say, Go or Ocaml for the latter I'd say.

Comment: +1 but cannot accept the answer yet. Let me see if there is a way. I understand the use case of Erlang and it's my favorite language. Let me try it with escript.

Comment: I remember the behaviour was changed somewhat recently, so it may be that this is what has hit you.

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=regexdna&lang=hipe&id=7&data=u32q) for the fastest line oriented IO for Erlang known to me. Note the usage of `-noshell` and `-noinput` command line parameters. Key part is

```
read() ->
   Port = open_port({fd, 0, 1}, [in, binary, {line, 256}]),
   read(Port, 0, [], []).

read(Port, Size, Seg, R) ->
  receive
    {Port, {data, {eol, <<$>:8, _/binary>> = Line}}} ->
      read(Port, Size + size(Line) + 1, [],
        [iolist_to_binary(lists:reverse(Seg, [])) | R]);
    {Port, {data, {eol, Line}}} ->
      read(Port, Size + size(Line) + 1, [Line | Seg], R);
    {'EXIT', Port, normal} ->
      {Size, [list_to_binary(lists:reverse(Seg, [])) | R]};
    Other ->
      io:format(">>>>>>> Wrong! ~p~n", [Other]),
      exit(bad_data)
  end.
```

**EDIT**: Note that the line oriented IO was fixed in R16B http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-February/072531.html so you need this trick no longer.

**EDIT2**: There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46496325/49197) using fixed `file:read_line/1`.

Comment: This example is not helping me in solving the problem. Erlang newbie here ;).