# In Erlang/Elixir, what are some use cases for opening a port with file descriptors?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-ports

I've been poking around the `Port` module in Elixir, and discovered you can open ports by specifying file descriptors.  Examples...

```
# elixir
iex(1)> Port.open({:fd, 5, 10}, [])
#Port<0.1205>

# erlang
1> erlang:open_port({fd, 5, 10}, []). 
#Port<0.435>
```

What's a use case for opening a port this way?  And do you interact with the port?  The documentation for Erlang ports is pretty light, and I haven't found anything talking about ports & file descriptors.

Comment: Someone used `open_port({fd, ...})` in an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642198/erlang-how-to-pipe-stdin-input-from-a-file-to-an-erlang-program-and-match-eof

Comment: Another example here: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-June/027426.html and here: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-June/027423.html

Comment: @7stud thanks.  Very helpful, thanks.

Comment: The examples I looked at seem to use `open_port({fd,...`  to read from a "file" when you have a file descriptor that you got from somewhere.  Of course, a "file" can be a file, pipe, socket, etc.  `io:read` does not provide a way to read from a file descriptor.  But it looks like `file:pread()` does.  Maybe the difference is that with `open_port()` you receive the file as messages?