# How to efficiently read thousand of lines from STDIN in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, stdin

I've stumbled upon an issue when reading thousands of lines from STDIN. This would have been an imaginary edge case until I found out that some tests for [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-multiple) require reading thousand of lines from STDIN. At first I thought that my algorithms were not optimal, and only by accident I've found out that only reading lines without any computations could make half of the test time out.

Here is part code that times out:

```
process_queries(0, _) -> ok;
process_queries(N, A) -> 
    case io:fread("", "~s~d~d") of
        {ok, _} -> process_queries(N - 1, A)
        %{ok, ["Q", L, R]} -> process_queries(N - 1, apply_q(L, R, A));
        %{ok, ["U", Idx, Val]} -> process_queries(N - 1, apply_u(Idx, Val, A))
    end
.
```

I deliberately left comments to show that all the computations were disabled. So this code timed out given `N=7984`.

Is there a better way of reading and processing thousands lines from STDIN in Erlang?

- `io:get_line` gets only one line a time.
- `io:get_chars` requires you to know how many character to get.

Comment: I doubt that a hackerrank related issue that doesn't exist in the actual world of Erlang problems is something that will motivate much of a response. If you don't get a bite here, try IRC, or a real-world issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest switching stdio to binary and then using `io:get_line`. Your data's format is pretty simple to parse by splitting on whitespace and converting two values to integers. The following code runs ~10 times faster than your code for me in a simple benchmark. I used `escript` to benchmark, which means it's highly likely that the difference is actually more than 10 times since escript parses and compiles the code on the fly.

```
process_queries_2(0, _) -> ok;
process_queries_2(N, A) -> 
    Line = io:get_line(""),
    [X, Y0, Z0, _] = binary:split(Line, [<<$\s>>, <<$\n>>], [global]),
    Y = binary_to_integer(Y0),
    Z = binary_to_integer(Z0),
    % use X, Y, Z
    process_queries_2(N - 1, A).
```

Here's the code I used to benchmark:

```
main(["1"]) ->
  ok = io:setopts(standard_io, [binary]),
  process_queries(10000, {});
main(["2"]) ->
  ok = io:setopts(standard_io, [binary]),
  process_queries_2(10000, {}).%
```

```
$ time yes 'Q 100 200' | escript a.erl 1
yes 'Q 100 200'  4.64s user 0.11s system 93% cpu 5.063 total
escript a.erl 1  4.67s user 1.44s system 120% cpu 5.062 total
$ time yes 'Q 100 200' | escript a.erl 2
yes 'Q 100 200'  0.36s user 0.01s system 77% cpu 0.466 total
escript a.erl 2  0.40s user 0.10s system 106% cpu 0.464 total
```

The reason for the speedup is that Erlang Strings are linked lists, which are very inefficient both for CPU time and Memory usage compared to binaries, which is a sequential chunk of memory.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excerpt from my solution. There are few tricks how to do it really efficient.

```
read_command(CP) ->
    {ok, Line} = file:read_line(standard_io),
    [C, A, B] = binary:split(Line, CP, [global, trim_all]),
    {case C of <<"Q">> -> 'Q'; <<"U">> -> 'U' end,
     binary_to_integer(A),
     binary_to_integer(B)}.

read_commands(N, CP) ->
    [ read_command(CP) || _ <- lists:seq(1, N) ].

execute(Array, L) ->
    lists:foldl(fun({'Q', F, T}, A) ->
                        {Val, A2} = query(A, F, T),
                        file:write(standard_io, [integer_to_binary(Val), $\n]),
                        A2;
                   ({'U', I, V}, A) ->
                        update(A, I, V)
                end, Array, L).

read_int_line(CP) ->
    {ok, Line} = file:read_line(standard_io),
    [binary_to_integer(X) || X <- binary:split(Line, CP, [global, trim_all])].

main() ->
    ok = io:setopts([binary]),
    CP = binary:compile_pattern([<<" ">>, <<$\n>>]),
    [N] = read_int_line(CP),
    L = read_int_line(CP),
    N = length(L),
    [K] = read_int_line(CP),
    execute(init(L), read_commands(K, CP)).
```

You have to write your own `init/1`, `update/3` and `query/3` of course.

Comment: Thank you, I have a few questions. Why is `init/1` function needed? It looks like the whole array is in `L` already.

Comment: @m3nthal: Because I'm using different internal representation. `L` is a list, not an array. It has bad access characteristics. And I'm also using a different representation for numbers as well for a faster minimum common multiplier calculation.

Comment: I did some research and found out that dicts and maps would be faster for access and random update. How do you represent numbers? In binary format? Probably you are also using binary gcd algorithm?

Comment: @m3nthal: I represent numbers as ordered list of factors. Then you can find gcd as an intersection and lcm as a union. I do it using merge join. And for representing array I use a similar N-tree structure as used in [`array`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) module but reimplemented. (I wrote solution before `maps` become common.)