# How to speed up "Queue using Two Stacks" in Erlang

Tags: erlang

A common programming problem which I've done in Python, Java, etc. with no problem.  The following in Erlang (which I'm just learning) runs very slowly (~44s user time for 10^5 operations), and I am lost as to why.

As written on HackerRank, the program takes one line from `stdin` with an integer representing the number of operations that follow.  Each subsequent line should be `1 X` (enqueue X), `2` (dequeue and discard), or `3` (peek and print the next value on the queue).

Am I using `lists:reverse/1` incorrectly?

```
-module(two_stacks).
%% API exports
-export([main/1]).

enqueue(Num, F, B) ->
    {[Num | F], B}.
dequeue(F, []) ->
    [_|B] = lists:reverse(F),
    {[], B};
dequeue(F, [_|B]) -> 
    {F, B}.

peek(F, []) ->
    [H|T] = lists:reverse(F),
    io:format(H),
    {[], [H|T]};

peek(F, [H|T]) ->
    io:format(H),
    {F, [H|T]}.

dispatchOperation(_, {F, B}) ->
    [Code|Line] = io:get_line(""),

    case Code of
        49 -> 
            [_|Num] = Line,
            enqueue(Num, F, B);
        50 -> dequeue(F, B);
        51 -> peek(F, B)
    end.


main(_) ->
    {Count, _} = string:to_integer(io:get_line("")),
    _ = lists:foldl(fun dispatchOperation/2, {[], []}, lists:seq(1, Count)),
    erlang:halt(0).
```

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/queue-using-two-stacks/problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you running an [escript](https://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html)? If that's the case, you should add a `-mode(compile).` there, because otherwise it runs the script in interpreted mode.

Also, you can compare the times against using the [queue](https://erlang.org/doc/man/queue.html) module (which is implemented using two stacks)

Comment: Thank you for the tips, it helped lead me to the actual issue.  Very interesting to learn that the official queue module also uses two lists!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the way I'm parsing input.  See [46493207](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493207/how-to-efficiently-read-thousand-of-lines-from-stdin-in-erlang) for discussion.

Since all the inputs are integers I was able to make use of the same technique used there.  The completed code is:

```
-module(solution).
-export([main/0]).

enqueue(Num, F, B) ->
    {[Num | F], B}.
dequeue(F, []) ->
    [_|B] = lists:reverse(F),
    {[], B};
dequeue(F, [_|B]) -> 
    {F, B}.

peek(F, []) ->
    [H|T] = lists:reverse(F),
    io:format("~B~n", [H]),
    {[], [H|T]};

peek(F, [H|T]) ->
    io:format("~B~n", [H]),
    {F, [H|T]}.

run(_, {F, B}) ->
    Line = io:get_line(""),
    [X| Y] = binary:split(Line, [<<$\s>>, <<$\n>>], [global]),
    Code = binary_to_integer(X),

    case Code of
        1 -> 
            Num = binary_to_integer(lists:nth(1, Y)),
            enqueue(Num, F, B);
        2 -> dequeue(F, B);
        3 -> peek(F, B)
    end.


main() ->
    ok = io:setopts(standard_io, [binary]),
    {Count, _} = string:to_integer(io:get_line("")),
    _ = lists:foldl(fun run/2, {[], []}, lists:seq(1, Count)),
    erlang:halt(0).
```